Angular dev server (ng serve) does not start in interactive mode
I have various version angular v18 projects where in some the "ng serve" command presents the options for the local host server and others do not. What causes the dev server to start in interactive mode with the options h, q, o etc?
here is what I am getting getting

In some projects when I enter "ng serve" on the command line I get this :-
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
√ Compiled successfully.


here I enter ctrl C to quit the server.

In other V18 projects command "ng serve" produces this :-
➜  Local:   http://localhost:4200/
➜  press h + enter to show help


here h will give the available options, one of which
is "q" which replaces the Ctrl-c used to quit
*-*-*-

How do I get the second Quit option for all my projects? What controls the server listen options?
All of the project are Angular/Cli V18 but some are stuck on ng serve output 1 and others on ng serve output 2.
Tried:
I have updated to the latest v18, cleared npm cache, deleted node_modules and run npm install, all to no avail.
Version
    the version of node is v20.16.0    
 Angular: 18.2.12
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1802.12
@angular-devkit/build-angular   18.2.12
@angular-devkit/core            18.2.12
@angular-devkit/schematics      18.2.12
@angular/cdk                    18.2.13
@angular/fire                   18.0.1
@angular/material               18.2.13
@schematics/angular             18.2.12
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.5.4
zone.js                         0.14.10

above is an example of one of the versions that still gives the option 1 output
